# Crontab to upload file from Google Cloud (gsutil)

Tags: cron

I'm using a virtual machine on GCP, and every day I upload a new file (same name) to Storage, then use the Cloud Shell Terminal to upload the file to the virtual machine using:
gsutil cp gs://my_bucket/my_file .

I want to create a cronjob that will load the file to the VM at a scheduled time.

Here's my cron:
00 13 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/gsutil cp /home/user_name/ gs://mybucket/my file .

When I check the cron syslog, I see it ran:
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, so I'll post it here.
The problem was I was not providing the right path to gsutil and I didn't have the rest of the syntax correct.

Find the correct gsutil path by running:
gsutil version -l

In my case, the corrected cron was:
00 13 * * 1-5 /snap/google-cloud-sdk/147/bin/gsutil cp gs://mybucket/myfile.py ./

Note the ./ put the file in my home directory.
(Again, what I'm doing above is copying a file from my Google Cloud Storage bucket ("mybucket") to my virtual machine home directory.  It can then be run by another cronjob.)